# Save an attachment to my iDisk

Tags: email, mobileme, icloud

Is it possible to save a file received by e-mail to a folder on iDisk ? Watch out : The context is : web browsing on my MobileMe account.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it. It would be a good feature though. You should send them a feature request.